# c unknown Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am getting a Segmentation fault but I do not know why:

```
    // Assemble folderPositionString
    char *folderPositionString = "folders-";
    strcat (folderPositionString, "files");
```

In theory this should produce a single char string with 'folders-files' as the value.  I have used strcat before and it works, but for some reason it is not happy here.

If I comment out the strcat line, everything compiles and works.

**Working Code thanks to Eugene**

```
    char folderPositionString [50] = "folders.";
    strcat (folderPositionString, folderPositionRaw);   
    strcat (folderPositionString, ".files");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char \*s" but not "char s\[\]"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha)

Comment: `char *folderPositionString = "folders-";` is a string literal kept in **read only memory.** You are trying to change data in a **read only memory**, So are getting `seg fault`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`folderPositionString`  is pointing to a read-only memory where the string literal is allocated. When trying to write there additional data you are getting memory access violation.

**Update about the update:**

In the second case `query_string` is getting the same address value as `account_id`, which is presumably pointing to a non-read only memory region.

Comment: Eugene - On the second part, so I guess I am not taking the 'value' or account_id, rather I am pointing to its actual memory location?  I'm guessing I should revisit that code because that might have unintended consequences in that code as well.

Comment: For the 1st part - would it be better to set folderPositionString using [] or do I need to alloc memory differently?

Comment: It is value of `account_id`, which is interpreted as address (i hope for you it is valid). If you change `folderPositionString` to [], yes it will behave differently and just initialize the writable array with this string. But don't forget to set it's size to a sufficient number to contain the concatenated string.

Comment: Thank you Eugene, that fixed it.  I have updated my question with the finalized code.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Please revert the original question. It is a Q&A site, which means it has to contain valid questions and answers.